# How do I tell if the content of an academic conference is available?

Tags: conference

A [post](https://www.escrs.org/paris2019/programme/posters-details.asp?id=33151) on an official site gives Abstract Details about a presentation.

However I didn't see a link to see or buy the full content.

How do I tell if the content of this presentation is available?

Comment: This seems like a question for the conference site.  Or maybe a digital librarian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Availability varies of course. In some cases the conference has a (permanent) website that might detail such information. Or at least it can give you access to the program chair who can answer the question.

For conferences hosted by major professional organizations, there is probably a general policy, and even an established library. This is the case for ACM (Association for Computing Machinery) conferences.

But you can also contact the authors of the work. Even if the conference provides no repository, the authors can probably give you more information. Don't be hesitant about asking.